# How to calculate vwap (volume weighted average price) using groupby?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I want to calculate the VWAP value for each month (i.e. for each group created).

```
data['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).month
data.head()
data['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).year
data.head()
group = data.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])
group.first() 
data['VWAP'] = (np.cumsum(data['Close Price' * data['Total Traded 
Quantity']) / np.cumsum(data['Total Traded Quantity']))
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'quantity'

Comment: Could you add some example data, mostly 5-10 rows is enough to understand your problem.

Comment: your code doesn't contain any `quantity` as indicated in the error.

Comment: Looks like you put a newline after Total Traded. That is why it is complaining about no attribute named 'Quantity'

Comment: Thanks for the help guys i found the error. Just added this line 'data['VWAP'] = (data['Close Price'] * data['Total Traded Quantity']).cumsum() / data['Total Traded Quantity'].fillna(0).cumsum()
data.head()'

Answer (score 1):

You forget to write ']' after the data['Close Price'], here is my code

```
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
group = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])
df['VWAP'] = (np.cumsum(df['Close Price'] * df['Total Traded Quantity']) / np.cumsum(df['Total Traded Quantity']))
```

Thanks...